# How to be on google first page results?

Tags: seo, google, yahoo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I searched the web and find a lot of "techniques" to be on the first page results of google or yahoo.

Is it possible to pay for that?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://webmasters.stackechange.com. Please do not crosspost, it will be moved by a moderator shortly

Comment: open a Google AdWords account and pay Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no.
The only *real* way to get yourself higher in search rankings is to actually have the best/most relevant content for whatever the search is. There are services that will offer ways to do this, which often involve things like them placing links to your site in various directories at best, in spam farms at worst. The search engines actively work against this sort of thing and while you might see a temporary benefit, it almost certainly won't last, and might even end up harming you.

It's also worth noting that with the degree of customization and geotargeting that Google in particular does now, there's almost no such thing as a single "first page" for you to be aiming for. Make your site good and the rest will take care of itself.

You can, of course, buy your way into the ads that appear at the top of some search results(with the yellow background), but I don't think that's what you're asking about.